# Shared property file for all the JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Could you please advise me how can I setup single property file accessible for all reports and set the default value for parameter (with default value expression in iReport) something like $R{my.shared.property}. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to localize the value, you could add the property to `WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties` (in JasperReports Server) and then use `JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance()).getProperty("my.shared.property")` as parameter expression.  Rather verbose as you can see..

If you want to localize the property value, you can do something similar with resource bundle property files under `WEB-INF/classes` and `ResourceBundle.getBundle("shared_messages", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).getString("my.shared.property")` as value expression.

Comment: It seems that this solution fits. But I've got an error when opened the report: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter`

Comment: Post the report and full exception stacktrace, the exception message is not enough to tell anything.